# In which tablespace of a schema object is stored?

Tags: oracle11g

How to know in which tablespace schema objects below are stored in?

```
+ Tables, views, indexes
+ Triggers, Procedures, Functions
+ Package Spec, Package Body
+ User-defined types
+ Directory object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle documentaion:

> There is no relationship between schemas and tablespaces: a tablespace
>   can contain objects from different schemas, and the objects for a
>   schema can be contained in different tablespaces.

Read more from here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c11schem.htm

> All data stored on behalf of stored PL/SQL program units (procedures,
>   functions, packages and triggers) resides in the SYSTEM tablespace. If
>   you create many of these PL/SQL objects, the database administrator
>   needs to plan for the space in the SYSTEM tablespace that these
>   objects use

Comment: All data stored on behalf of stored PL/SQL program units (procedures, functions, packages and triggers) resides in the SYSTEM tablespace. If you create many of these PL/SQL objects, the database administrator needs to plan for the space in the SYSTEM tablespace that these objects use

Comment: How about MViews? Which query to know your MViews are stored in which tablespace?